# Jest: ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I am writing unit test using "react-testing-library" on Jest and I have this error:

```
 Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: global is not defined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:92:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/expect/build/toThrowMatchers.js:10:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/expect/build/index.js:35:48)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:261:3)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After I added `"jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.0.6"` as a dev dependency, that error went away.

Comment: this error removed the global issues, but gave me a new one in cannot use import statement outside a module off jest runtime.

Comment: for me, i didn't know i was using the old `jest-env*dom` package. removing it from the `package.json` helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I've just added ```"resolutions": {
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27"
 }``` to the package.json and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using angular v13 with jest v27.2.3 and tsjest v27.0.5
and my problem was with the configuration of jest.config.ts files and what solves it for me was this configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'myApp',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$'
    }
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/myapp',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!lodash-es/.*)',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!ng2-charts/.*)',
    '^.+\\.js$'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^lodash-es$': 'lodash'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
  ]
};
```

or to libs

```
module.exports = {
  displayName: 'myLib',
  preset: '../../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$'
    }
  },
  coverageDirectory: '../../../coverage/libs/...',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment'
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for me downgrading jest/typejest version from 27 to 26 fixed this. found the fix from this github issues.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10957